# How to use tf.Transform Analyzer variables in preprocessing_fn

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-transform, tfx

How can I use a tf.Transform analyzer variable within the preprocessing_fn of my TFX pipeline?

I am using the tft.max function to compute the maximum value over the whole dataset, which is defined as an analyzer from looking at the source code. I want to use the result of this analyser in the following function call, but get the following error:

**The transform function**

```
def preprocessing_fn(inputs):
    outputs = {}
    max_length = tft.max(inputs['MFCC_frame_count'], reduce_instance_dims=True)
    outputs['MFCC_data'] = tft.sparse_tensor_to_dense_with_shape(
        inputs['MFCC_data'],
        [max_length, 26],
        default_value=0
    )
    return outputs
```

**The error**

```
TypeError: Dimension value must be integer or None or have an __index__ method, got <tf.Tensor 'max/min_and_max/Placeholder_1:0' shape=() dtype=int64>
```

How can I use this value? I have tried a number of different things to use this value, but nothing seems to work.

**Our data**

```
context {
  feature {
    key: "MFCC_data"
    value {
      float_list {
        value: 6.972537994384766
        value: -24.602876663208008
        value: -18.28076934814453
        ...
      }
    }
  }
  feature {
    key: "MFCC_frame_count"
    value {
      int64_list {
        value: 316
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

**In our interactive pipeline**

```
transform = Transform(
      examples=example_gen.outputs['examples'],
      schema=schema_gen.outputs['schema'],
      module_file='transform.py')
context.run(transform)
```

**Relevant versions**

```
Python 3.7.3
tfx==0.15.0
tensorflow==2.1.0
tensorflow-transform==0.15.0
```

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Else, can you try using the combination of `tf.sparse.reshape` and `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead of `tft.sparse_tensor_to_dense_with_shape`. Note that your current preprocessing_fn doesn't look right to me, as tf.Transform performs a map of the inputs to the outputs, the batch dimension should most likely be the same for tensors in inputs and tensors in outputs (i.e. the first dimension in the output shape should be batch_size, not max_length).